# Phpbrowser and hidden field

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, browser, automated-tests

I using phpbrowser to test my scripts. When i am trying to set value of hidden field

```
$I->fillField('Billing[packageId]', "15");
```

it returns an error. Does anybody can help how i can solve problem?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the form html?
It seems that there's no input field named `Billing[packageId]` in your form.

EDIT:
You're trying to fill a field named `Billing[packageId]` but in your code there's `Billing[packageType]`.

In addition, I think that `hidden` fields are not supposed to be filled with user input so I don't know if phpBrowser lets you do that.

Comment: Hi!  Billing[packageId] - it is hidden field. 

`<input type="hidden" name="Billing[packageType]" value="" helper="formHidden" id="Billing-packageType">`

And it is IN <form></form>